# Spring JPA Empty List using Query Method

Tags: spring, spring-data-jpa

Entity contains List.  How do you use Query Method to check if list is empty aka size = 0?

Comment: it would be helpful if you provided current attempted code or did some research on the matter

Comment: class A {
 String id
 List<B> b
}
.....
A findByIdAndBIsEmpty(String Id)

Answer (score 0):

You can use IS EMPTY in JPQL.

Example:

```
select p from Person p where p.languages IS EMPTY
```

Using the JPA EntityManager:

```
TypedQuery<Person> q = 
    entityManager.createQuery("select p from Person p where p.languages IS EMPTY", Person.class);

List<Person> people = q.getResultList();
```

Comment: I added an example to my answer.

Comment: i am trying to find something like this : findByIdAndListIsEmpty(String Id) ... not using entity manager or using @Query

Comment: According to https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/ this should work.